# Seg fault occurs when copying char pointer into array of char pointers

Tags: c, pointers, strcpy

I am reading in a line of text from a file, and trying to split it on spaces with `strtok()`, then storing each token in an array of char pointers using `strcpy()`, within a function called `tokenize`.

Code:

```
/**
** Tokenizes contents of buffer into words
** Delimiter is a space character
*/
void tokenize(char *buffer, char *tokens[]){
    char *token = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    token = strtok(buffer, " ");
    while(token != NULL){
        strcpy(tokens[i], token);//seg fault line
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }
}
```

I assumed, based on the function description in K&R, that my call would work because I passed a char pointer, which is what `tokens[i]` should dereference to, and a another char pointer containing the memory address of the string to be copied, which is what `token` should be. However, I get a seg fault when I try to `strcpy`.

This function is called in `main` immediately after a line is retrieved using a call to `fgets()`. `buffer` is declared as `char buffer[MAXLINE_LEN - 1]` which gives it a size of 100. `tokens` is declared as `char *tokens[MAXLINE_LEN - 1]`.

Call to `tokenize` in `main`:

```
while(fgets(buffer, MAXLINE_LEN, inputFile)){
    int choice;
    printf("%s", buffer);
    tokenize(buffer, tokens);
    /**
    ....
    */
}
```

I am using: `gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609`

**EDIT:**
Declaration of `tokens` (this occurs before the while-loop shown above, and in `main`):

```
char *tokens[MAXLINE_LEN - 1];//MAXLINE_LEN - 1 = 100

int a;
for(a = 0; a < MAXLINE_LEN - 1; a++)
    tokens[a] = NULL;
```

Comment: your issue revolves around the declaration / init of `tokens` that you're not showing us.

Comment: `tokens[i] = malloc(strlen(token)+1);` before `strcpy(tokens[i], token);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I have to allocate heap memory for each char pointer in `tokens`? Isn't memory allocated when I first declare `tokens` in main?

Comment: Will downvoter clarify please?

Comment: Pointers are allocated in arrays. But It is not the area pointed to by the pointer.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I'm not sure I understand. More importantly, how do I free the `malloc` memory after I am done with it?

Comment: if You initialize each elements like `tokens[a] = NULL;` , `for(int i = 0; tokens[i]; ++i) free(tokens[i]);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140154/discussion-between-ungeheuer-and-bluepixy).

Answer (score 0):

There are four possibilities I can think of

1. `tokens` is `NULL` or uninitialised
2. `tokens` is initialised but you haven't allocated enough space. What if you allocate space for four tokens but `strtok()` parses five tokens?
3. The individual elements of `tokens` are n`NULL` or uninitialised
4. You didn't allocate enough space in each elemant to copy a token string.

One or more of those almost certainly applies to your code. One way to fix it would be to completely allocate `tokens` inside the function and return it in a pointer (with the count as the return value).

```
enum
{
    CHUNK_SIZE = 16; // A trick to get an int constant in C that works everywhere a #define works
};

size_t tokenize(char *buffer, char **tokenRet[])
{
    size_t capacity = 0;
    char** tokens = NULL;
    size_t count = 0;
    char *token = NULL;
    token = strtok(buffer, " ");
    while(token != NULL)
    {
        count++;
        if (count > capacity)
        {
            capacity += CHUNK_SIZE;
            tokens = realloc(tokens, capacity * sizeof *tokens);
        }
        tokens[count - 1] = strdup(token);//strdup mallocs space and copies the string into it
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    *tokenRet = tokens;
    return count;
}
```

Call it like this

```
char** myTokens = NULL;
size_t tokenCount = tokenize(buffer, &myTokens);
```

Then to tidy up at the end, `free()` the first `tokenCount` elements of `myTokens` and then free `myTokens`.

Comment: is `**tokenRet[] a three dimensional array of char pointers? Why would I need this? I'm new to C, and pointers are doing a doozy on my brain, esp. at 5am

Comment: No `tokenRet` is a pointer to an array of pointers to `char`. In this case you can think of it as a pointer to an array of strings. The reason it needs the extra indirection is so that tokenize can reach back into its caller and change the array of strings declared there to be the array that it has built from buffer.

Comment: `char* myTokens[] = NULL;` --> `char** myTokens = NULL;`

Answer (score -1):

What is the size of "char *tokens[]"?
It is possible that you have more tokens in "char *buffer" than tokens[] can hold.
Also, did you allocate memory for the array of pointers?

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, `tokens` is declared to have a size of 100. It is not possible for `buffer` to hold more than 100 tokens, as it contains 100 characters. At most then, there could be 50 tokens in `buffer` if each token was a single character with a space between each one.

Comment: Did you allocate memory for each tokens[] pointer before passing down to tokenize()?

Comment: No I didn't. I assumed they would be allocated memory when I declared the array, in face, they have 8 bytes which is the proper pointer size for my machine. If I did use a malloc call before passing them to tokenize, I would have no idea how much to allocate to each pointer. Also, what would I be allocating memory for/to?